# Accessing Cpanel Folder and consuming files from it in app

Tags: android, api, cpanel

I am building media player app which will play the audio files present in my hostgator hosting. i don't have domain for it. the files are present in the directory in file manager of cpanel.

i am unable to get the url to hit the api, 
so from where i can get the url 
and do i have to used http connection or ftp protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

having a domain name is always preferable if you need to integrate the API , so register a domain name , host it and move the files in order to get an URL

Comment: well i want to make number of different applications, then i will have to get domain every time.